# If $f(z)$ is analytic in a domain D then show that $f^2(z)$ is analytic there.

Tags: analytic-functions, cauchy-riemann-equations

If $f(z)$ is analytic in a domain D then show that $f^2(z)$ is analytic there.

Let $f(z)=u+iv$, then $f^2=u^2-v^2+2iuv=X+iY$, say

then by CR equation due to analyticitiy, it can be shown that CR equations hold for $f^2$.

But how to show that $f^2(z)$ is analytic in D?

Comment: Given some function on some complex domain, have you seen examples of how to show that it is analytic? Recall those examples, and repeat the procedure for $f^2$. You definitely saw the CR equations. Can you recall the theorem relating CR equations to analyticity?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $f$ is analytic in $D$. Then for any $z\in D$,
\begin{align*}
& \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{f^2 (z + h) - f^2(z)}}{h} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{(f(z + h) - f(z))(f(z + h) + f(z))}}{h}
\\ &
 = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{f(z + h) - f(z)}}{h}\mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} (f(z + h) + f(z)) = f'(z) \cdot 2f(z),
\end{align*}
i.e., $f^2$ is also analytic in $D$ and $(f^2(z))'=2f'(z)f(z)$.

Comment: $f(z)=u+i v$ analitic u and v are continious in the domain D so $u^{2}, v^{2},uv are also continious so can be claim from here the analyticity of $f^{2}(z)

Comment: @Butane Could you please reformulate your comment? It is a bit of a mess.

Comment: @Butane yes, X and Y are continuous, but is it not required that X and Y have continuous partial derivatives also?

Comment: It is a sufficient condition for $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ differentiability. Of course it happens in this case. For example, $\frac{{\partial u^2 (x,y)}}{{\partial x}} = 2u(x,y)\frac{{\partial u(x,y)}}{{\partial x}}$ is continuous because, by assumption, the right-hand side is a product of continuous functions.

Comment: Sorry for messy writing and thanks for your answers @Gary I got it.